# have a solution for (typeof !== 'undefined') in functions?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a arrow function to check my vars or values, but I don't know how to resolve this. In normal expression(out the function) it's works, but in a function the value is checked before the condition and returns a error. Have a way to ignore or remove this error similar to '@' in PHP?

```
//the function:
var isValid = value => typeof value !== 'undefined' && value ? true : false;
```

How to Works:

```js
var isValid = value => typeof value !== 'undefined' && value ? true : false;

var is_exists = 1;

console.log('//normal expression test with existing variable:');
console.log(typeof is_exists !== 'undefined' && is_exists ? true : false);

console.log('//normal expression test with nonexistent variable:');
console.log(typeof is_noexists !== 'undefined' && is_noexists ? true : false);

console.log('//arrow function test with existing variable:');
console.log(isValid(is_exists));

console.log('//arrow function test with noexisting variable:');
console.log(isValid(is_noexists));
```

NOTE: The condition can be reduced to `typeof value !== 'undefined' && !!value`

Comment: it has nothing to do with the function.. it has something to do with you cant pass a non existent var into a function.. the error happens **BEFORE** the function even begins executing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the general case, it's not possible, at least not in any reasonable way.

When you pass an argument to a function, the interpreter must be able to extract the value that the argument contains *at that point*, before anything inside the function runs. If `someVar` has never been defined, you cannot reference it unless you do a `typeof` check first. So, the logic you're trying to implement is not possible to abstract into a separate function; you must check that the variable is defined at the call site, before each function call.

That said, this is a *weird* problem to have. Dynamic variable names are quite strange and should be avoided in most cases. If you find yourself having to do something like this, consider if it would be at all possible to structure your data differently, such as putting the possibly-existing values into a *single object* instead, eg:

```
const obj = {
  value1: 'foo
};

// dynamically added property:
obj.value2 = 'bar';

// ...

console.log(Boolean(obj.value1));
console.log(Boolean(obj.value2));
```

This way, even if the properties inside `obj` can vary dynamically, the only *variable name* - the `obj` - remains constant. This pattern is much easier to manage.

Comment: I didn't think for this way, I just thought of creating something that would solve any problem that I might have, but after reading your explanation I understood that in fact it is not even necessary. Thanks for help me to understand better this problem =)